# Number of distinct sums in array?

Tags: algorithm

Given an array consisting only numbers which are power of 2. Find number of distinct possible sums of subsets, such that each element is taken atmost once.

If all elements are distinct ans is simply 2^n. How should I approach if elements are not distinct? How to handle carry of 1?

Elements can contain upto 30 digits. Any O(n*log(30)) solution?

Comment: Show your efforts and make it apparent...!

Comment: It's not my homework. I was asked this in interview today.

Comment: So what is your idea for the simpler case you mentioned?